# export the data from db with double quotes into csv in php

Tags: php, csv

i have some data in mysql with double quotes.. when i export it into csv it doesn't support the double quotes.. Please help me..

echo $csv_output="9"Strawberry;

in excel file it doesn't found

Comment: str_replace( '"' , "''" ,$fetch['Description']); 

it will be correct for my question.. Thanks all for getting idea to solve this....

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes. You need to change a double quote to **two** double quotes.

For example:

```
echo $csv_output="9"Strawberry;
```

would need to be:

```
echo $csv_output=str_replace('"','""','"9"Strawberry');
```

or even

```
echo $csv_output=str_replace('"','""',$value_from_db);
```

For more details, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example

Comment: "9"Strawberry is fetch from database

Comment: no change the same will be displayed again.. if double quotes appear the next data's are also cannot be displayed

Comment: str_replace('"',"''",$fetch['Description']);

Comment: @Ram: Can you post more of your code and a small sample of the csv output.

Comment: Self Adhesive Tape 18mm x 15m (GP)
 Self Adhesive Tape 18mm x 15m (GP) Bamboo
 ''10'' Black Stripes Yellow Acrylic Long Pile Roller Set
 Self Adhesive Tape 18mm x 40m (GP)
 Self Adhesive Tape 18mm x 40m (GP) Bamboo
 BOPP Tape 40 Mic 72mm x 50m (Brown)
 BOPP Tape 40 Mic 72mm x 50m (Brown) Bamboo..                                                             In the above csv example ''10'' is not displayed by using the       str_replace('"',"''",$fetch['Description']);  the problem will be solved

Comment: @Ram: Please update the original question with the new info - do not post it as a comment. If that is a copy and paste job of the data... the 10 is surrounded by four single quotes ['] (two on each side) not double quotes ["], which points to a different issue. Also, you did not include any code. Without the code, it is impossible to help locate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

while exporting data to CSV file use following code to remove single quote .

```
$value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
```

it will replace your single quote  with double quote

Comment: the same will be appear again